# Hbase Maven build from source

Tags: maven, hadoop, hbase

I am new to maven build architecture [.Hbase official website](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/build.html) explains Building tar ball through this command:

```
mvn clean site install assembly:assembly -DskipTests -Prelease
```

But I couldn't find anywhere that where final binary tar ball has been created?
I understand its from `/hbase-assembly/src/main/assembly/src.xml`

But based on this assembly file properties there is no tar ball has been created?So where exactly binary tar ball will be created?

Answer (score 5):

here is my quick how to build and run hbase. but the short answer is you find the binary in hbase-assembly/target

```
$ git clone https://github.com/apache/hbase.git
$ cd hbase
$ git checkout branch-1.2
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests assembly:single
$ tar xzvf hbase-assembly/target/hbase-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-bin.tar.gz
$ export HBASE_HOME=`pwd`/hbase-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT/
$ export PATH=$HBASE_HOME/bin:$PATH
$ start-hbase.sh
$ hbase shell
```

Comment: how to build the same with different hadoop.profile. I want to build it against hadoop 3